# gambling strategy diagram

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, martingales, gambling

In this example, I am unable to understand how the author arrived at the values present in the last two tables.

**What I know**: (filling in the claim made by the author)

Claim: If win occurs at W=1, the net loss is -31

Proof:
$-1+(-2^{1})+(-2^{2})+(-2^{3})+(-2^{4})=-31$

Claim: If win occurs at W=2, the net loss is -15
Proof: $-1+(-2^{1})+(-2^{2})+(-2^{3})=-15$

Claim: If win occurs at W=3, the net loss is -7
Proof: $-1+(-2^{1})+(-2^{2})=-7$

Claim: If win occurs at W=4, the net loss is -3
Proof: $-1+(-2^{1})=-3$

Summing up gives -63 as is mentioned.

**Now**, I do not understand part where the author speaks about "the negative values....".
His intent is difficult to decipher.

> 6,5,4,3,2,1 refers to the time L of the loss, I believe
>
> The values that follows below is unclear.

$\space$

> the values -1,...,-63 is unclear as to where they were derived from
>
> the values below that follows is also very much unclear as to their origin.

I apologise for the terse description but I've spend hours on this just trying to understanding what the author is trying to convey!

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: Essential of stochastic process by Rick Durrett. In hindsight, I would not have learnt from this book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Combination}&\text{Winnings}\\
\hline WWW&+3\\
\hline WWL&+1\\
\hline WLW&+2\\
\hline WLL&-2\\
\hline LWW&+2\\
\hline LWL&+0\\
\hline LLW&+1\\
\hline LLL&-7\\\hline
\end{array}$$

What auther there is saying that winnings of $-63$ occurs $1$ out of $64$ times, $-1$ occurs $3$ times out of $64$ and so on.

As you can see in the example negative winnings are less frequent but are "heavier" in a sense that they cost you more

Moreover, The expected winnings, due to these "heavy" losses is always 0 (assuming P(Win)=P(Loss)=$50\%$

The author arrived at those negative values simply by listing all possible scenarios and counting. (There might be a more sophisticated way but i'm not sure about that)

Comment: If 6 games are played, why are there no 6 alphabets?

Comment: I'm ditching this example. It's hopeless with the way he's going about.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are not able to understand. Why would you require 6 alphabets for? There are 64 possible outcomes and auther has listed all of them (albiet the positive and negative winnings in different tables)

Comment: I took another approach to understand it but I'll give accept your answer.